# References about algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

My question is very simple. I'm studying a course telling about algebraic surfaces but i think that i need some knowledge about basic algebraic geometry. Do you have some suggestions?

Comment: I found Gathmann's note very helpful. (http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/agag/mitglieder/professoren/gathmann/notes/alggeom/)

Comment: There are introductory books by Hulek, Reid, Shafarevich, Hassett, Smith--Kahanpää--Kekäläinen, Perrin, and others. Shafarevich is the one I know best: it has flaws, but is reasonably comprehensive.

Comment: This is (arguably) the most elementary book for learning algebraic geometry I have come across: https://bookstore.ams.org/stml-66

Answer (score 0):

This book may be of some interest:

[ALGEBRAIC CURVES - An Introduction to Algebraic Geometry](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) by William Fulton.